# For loop and zip in python

Tags: python, for-loop, zip

I have a code that I am trying to understand and I need help.

```
import numpy as np
Class_numbers=np.array(['a','b','c'])
students_per_class=np.array([10,20,30])
print("Students counts per class:\n{}".format(
{x: y for x, y in zip(Class_numbers, students_per_class)}))
```

output:

```
Students counts per class:
{'a': 10, 'b': 20, 'c': 30}
```

What I understand:
1- we use {} and .format(...) to replace {} with ...

Here are my questions:

Q1- I do not understand "for x, y in zip(Class_numbers, students_per_class)". Is it like a 2d for loop? why we need the zip? Can we have 2d loop with out zip function?

Q2-I am not understanding how x:y works! the compile understand automatically that the definition of x and y (in "x:y") is described in the rest of the line(e.g. for loop)?

P.S: I am expert in MATLAB but I am new to python and it is sometimes very confusing!

Ehsan

Comment: self-proclaimed experts usually claim they know more than they do

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q1: `zip` is used to merge 2 lists together. It returns the first element of each list, then 2nd element of each list, etc. This is a trick to consider the two lists as key and data to create a dictionary.

Q2: this is a dictionary (hash), using a method called "dict comprehension". It creates the dictionary shown as the output. If assigned to a variable `d`, `d['a'] = 10`, etc.

Answer (score 21):

**zip** allows you to iterate two lists at the same time, so, for example, the following code

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
numbers = [1, 2, 3]

for letter, number in zip(letters, numbers):
    print(f'{letter} -> {number}')
```

gives you as output

```
a -> 1
b -> 2
c -> 3
```

when you iterate with zip, you generate two vars, corresponding to the current value of each loop.

Answer (score 2):

> zip is useful to enumerate the elements in the 2 different list and
> make a single list
>
> example :

```
 x: y for x, y in zip(Class_numbers, students_per_class)
```

> explanation:

- the element form Class_number is assigned to x which is a "Key" for the dictionary
  and the students_per_class is assigned to y which is a "value
- until the loop end it will iterate to dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

just print the line you don't understand to make it clearer...

first we define 2 arrays

```
Class_numbers=np.array(['a','b','c'])
['a','b','c']

students_per_class=np.array([10,20,30])
[10,20,30]
```

zip just add them together like

```
[('a', 10), ('b', 20), ('c', 30)]
```

now we iterate on each element with x and y and create a `dict` object (hash map) `{ key : value}`

```
{'a': 10, 'c': 30, 'b': 20}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a trick in using zip:

```
letters = ('A', 'B', 'C')
numbers = ('1', '2', '3')
let_num = zip(letters, numbers)
```

use the list() function to display zip:

```
print(list(let_num))
```

above code will produce

[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3')]

please note that, if you want to print again, this will not print anything since we already consumed the zip

```
print(list(let_num))
```