# How can I find the closest pair with the smallest difference in a single array?

Tags: python

I have a code that creates a list of 20 random integers between 1 and 1000. And In the case of multiple existences of closest pair, I have to display the smallest pair.

This is what I have so far:

```
import random

numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for num in range(20)]
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Which bits of the question are you having problems with? Do you know how to find the difference between two numbers? Do you know how to produce pairs of numbers from a list? Did you find any answers to these common problems on Stackoverflow?

Comment: "This is what I have so far" This doesn't seem to do anything of what you are asking about – it calculates neither the difference, nor does it attempt to find a minimum. What *exactly* are you struggling with?

Comment: I'm really sorry if you find my problem a problem. I'm new to programming and python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggesting using numpy:

```
import random
import numpy as np

numbers = np.array([random.randint(1, 100) for num in range(20)])
numbers.sort()
# calc diff:
diff = numbers[1:] - numbers[:-1]
# get index minimal diff:
argmin = diff.argmin()
pair = numbers[argmin:argmin+2]
```

Output:

```
print(numbers) # already sorted
>>> [ 1  6  7  8 11 15 18 37 47 54 60 61 61 73 73 78 82 85 87 94]
print(diff)
>>> [ 5  1  1  3  4  3 19 10  7  6  1  0 12  0  5  4  3  2  7]
print(pair) 
>>> array([61, 61])
```

This method will work in your case.

edit: not advised but you can do the same using a for loop:

```
numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for num in range(20)]
# sort:
numbers = sorted(numbers)
pairs = list(zip(numbers[:-1], numbers[1:]))
diff = []
for left, right in pairs:
    diff.append( right - left )
# get min index:
argmin = diff.index( min(diff) )

# pair:
pair = numbers[argmin:argmin+2]
```

edit2: But if you do want to go with a pure python solution I really like @Pychopath his answer.

Comment: This is why I really like python, the language really simplifies solving problems. I have 26 lines of codes and this is just a simplified version, thank you so much for this.

Comment: I have a question, I already research about numpy. But what did the numpy module specifically do in the problem?

Comment: It made it possible to vectorize your problem. This means that you can use `number[1:] - numbers[:-1]` which is better readable and numpy is much faster than looping over a list (especially with large lists). All of this is possible using normal lists, but then you have to loop over all elements and stuff. I will add one of the solutions (which is not shown here but is in my opinion readable).

Comment: I edited my anser, but as you can see it take much more time to understand what is going on and it does not improve the code. If you are learning to understand python it is good to get a thorough understanding of lists and how thinks work, but if you understand you can use the tools which are there to improve your code in speed and readability.

Comment: Hello, for the for loop, I have a question, how does it work? Why is there a left and right? I tried to research about it, but I still don't understand it. And what does zip() do?

Comment: Please look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783594/for-loop-and-zip-in-python (comments are not large enough to give you more examples, but there is a lot material out there about `python`, `zip` and `for loop`, so I am confident that you will find you answers when you use a search engine like Google.

Answer (score 6):

Sort and find the pair of adjacent numbers with the minimum difference:

```
from itertools import pairwise

result = min(pairwise(sorted(numbers)),
             key=lambda pair: pair[1] - pair[0])
```

Before Python 3.10:

```
numbers.sort()
result = min(zip(numbers, numbers[1:]),
             key=lambda pair: pair[1] - pair[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, you get something like:
Output:

```
[38, 88, 57, 19, 54, 13, 90, 99, 6, 87, 56, 42, 51, 77, 67, 77, 17, 31, 7, 87]
```

by your code and you want to find the two numbers that have the smallest difference?

I would start off by sorting the list:

```
sorted_list = sorted(numbers)
```

Output:

```
[6, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 38, 42, 51, 54, 56, 57, 67, 77, 77, 87, 87, 88, 90, 99]
```

Then I would loop over the sorted list and keep track of the difference like in the code below:

```
min_difference = float('inf')  # initialize the minimum difference with + infinity
result = [None, None]
for i in range(1, len(sorted_numbers)):
    num_a = sorted_numbers[i-1]  # get the element from the previous index. That's why we start off in the for loop at 1
    num_b = sorted_numbers[i]  # get the element from the current index
    difference = num_b - num_a  # calculate the difference. Since you only have positive numbers and the list is sorted this is working. In case you also want to include negative numbers you can write abs(num_b - num_a) to get the absolute difference for two numbers.
    if difference < min_difference:
        min_difference = min(difference, min_difference)  # the built-in min method returns the minimum from the elements passed to it. Here I update the minimum difference.
        result = [num_a, num_b]  # Here I save the two numbers with the minimum difference so far in the results list.
    if num_b - num_a == 0:  # Smallest difference is 0
        break  # Exits the for-loop

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[77, 77]
```

Hope this helps and hope I understood the problem correctly!

Comment: you have to update `min_difference` when you update `result`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Can you add more comments for me to understood what the different block of codes do, I am a beginner so I'm having a hard time understanding, and I really want to understand it. And yes, you understood the problem. Thank you!

Comment: @AlexisAubreyBrusola I just added some more comments. Hope they help.

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want the smallest pair, what you cant do is sort your list (or of copy of your list depending on your needs) with `sort()`.

```py
import random

numbers = [random.randint(1, 100) for num in range(20)]
numbers.sort()

print(numbers)
```

Then by iterating over the list, if a number is at more than 1 position, it is the smallest pair, so we can break the loop.

```py
smallestPair = None
for n in numbers:
    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(numbers) if x == n]
    if len(indices) > 1: # means there is more than 1 occurence of this number
        smallestPair = n
        break

print(smallestPair)
```

Comment: This doesn't find *closest* numbers, it only finds *equal* numbers. And thus if there aren't any equals, this doesn't find anything.

Comment: You are right, my english is at fault. For me a pair is formed by identical numbers. I understand now why the other answers where considering every numbers ... Thank you